# Colocar imagen como puntero

Tags: html, css

Buenas, he estado cambiando el puntero por otros estilos como "wait", "crooshair", etc. No obstante soy incapaz de cambiar el cursor por alguna imagen que tengo el el pc.

## HTML

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="DH18.js"></script>
 <link rel="StyleSheet" href="DH18.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="body">
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
#body {
cursor: url("icono.png");
}
```

PD: No pongo la ubicación concreta de la imagen ya que el documento html, css y dicha imagen se encuentran en la misma carpeta. Igualmente puse la dirección completa y no sirvió.

Comment: ¿Que navegador y sistema operativo usas?

Comment: vendeta, body no es un ID(osea sin #), es body {}, no necesitas colocarle ID

Comment: Ya lo puse sin # igualmente no funciona.   Navegador: Google Chrome   Sistema Operativo: Windows 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dos apuntes, las limitaciones del tamaño de imagen son de 128x128 aunque se recomienda usar un maximo de 32x32 para compatibilidad con el resto de SO y navegadores.

Todo sacado de la [documentacion de firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) ([en castellano](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/Uso_de_URL_como_valor_de_la_propiedad_cursor)):

> Esto es, se pueden indicar cero o más direcciones URL (separadas por
>   comas), que **deben** ser seguidas de uno de los cursores genéricos
>   definidos en la especificación, por ej. `auto`, `help` o `pointer`.

Tienes que añadirle el `auto` al final, o cualquier modo que deseas para el caso en el que el navegador no soporte la opción `url`

```css
p:hover {
  cursor: url("https://www.aciprensa.com/icons/32x32/mail.png"), auto;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: url("https://www.aciprensa.com/icons/32x32/mail.png");
}
```

```html
<p>Funciona</p>
<label>No funciona</label>
```

Comment: Hola @Hictus. Gracias por tu respuesta. Te recomendaría que la próxima vez mantuvieras en tu respuesta la parte más relevante de los enlaces que proporcionas. Nunca se sabe cuándo pueden dejar de funcionar éstos. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, muchas gracias por la edición, podrías indicarme como puedo poner el código ejecutable así por favor? No encuentro donde explican como hacerlo... Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por supuesto @Hictus. En tu editor verás un icono (a la derecha del de insertar imagen) que se describe como "fragmento HTML/JavaScript/CSS". Al pulsarlo te saldrá un editor y en la vista preliminar verás un enlace para "editar este fragmento de código".

Comment: @OscarGarcia Buuuua, mas cerca y me lo como, muchísimas gracias señor, se acabaron los enlaces a jsfiddle, yuhuu!

Answer (score 3):

Hay que indicar siempre un cursor genérico, si no quieres poner uno específico puedes poner `auto`. Ejemplo:

```css
#prueba{
  cursor: url("https://image.freepik.com/iconos-gratis/inicio-icono-silueta_318-85097.jpg"), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="prueba">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati dolorem explicabo nulla ex molestias! Ad doloremque maxime placeat cupiditate unde explicabo quibusdam repudiandae eaque inventore mollitia, reprehenderit sequi neque in?</div>
```